# Angular router navigation changes url, but doesn't render component

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, url-routing, path-parameter

I am working on an angular application with routing and path parameter. With a button click, a function is called to redirect the user to a new URL with the same path parameter. Although the URL in the browser changes, the corresponding component defined in app-routing.module.ts is not loaded. If I refresh the page again, the correct page is rendered.

The idea is that a student gets a unique URL with a hash token (e. g. `/student/33192c29aa8e449e94f3a1c4eef43ca8`), which shows him some guidelines. Afterwards with a click he should be forwarded to a registration page with the same token (e. g. `/student/registration/33192c29aa8e449e94f3a1c4eef43ca8`)

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'student/registration/:token', component: RegistrationsComponent },
  { path: 'student/:token', component: GuidelinesComponent },
  ...
];
```

**guidelines.component.html**

```
forwardToRegistration(): void {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/student/registration/' + this.studentToken);
}
```

The URL is updating correctly in the browser, but the RegistrationComponent is not rendered.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It works when you comment your second path in routes?

Comment: Well, the URL loads correctly. Only by using the method ```this.router.navigateByUrl(...)``` the URL is changed, but the component is not rendered. If I refresh the page without any further actions, the correct page is loaded. Furthermore, the variable ```this.studentToken``` holds the Path-Parameter hash token, which is read from the ActivatedRoute Params.

Comment: Well, if you are able to reproduce your problem in a stackbliz project to share with us I am sure that we can help you because seems like the problem could come from other place. Please consider to build a reproducible scenario.

Comment: curious if you got this to work as I am having the same issue.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and figured it out.
Maybe your cant see the content change because you dont have router-outlet tag in the app.component.html.
The url will change the content of

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

so you should placed the router-outlet tag in the app.component.html.

Comment: router outlet is there, but stll not workin

Answer (score 3):

@RobLasch almost had it.

in short, you want to subscribe to activatedRoute.params.
You do not want to subscribe to the entire activatedRoute.

here is a great video that walks you through it
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/

i dont see the component constructor in ops posting, so here is the one I have...

this works and inspecting the console, you are not getting any extra iterations... it just behaves like you would expect!

component constructor...

```
  constructor( 
              private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) {
        
                 
                this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( (data) => {
                     
                    const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('token');
                    console.log('router subscription fired token:' + token);
                    if(null == token) return;
                    this.getDetail();   //do whatever you need to do
                  })
        }
```

callingcomponent.ts

```
  itemClicked(evt: MouseEvent, item_: project) {
           
           
          this.router.navigate(['/students/' + item_.token]);
    }
```

Comment: Thakns for that! I moved the block of code that is initializing the variables inside the subscription of the activatedRoute and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by listening to router changes in the component which should be refreshed.

Step 1.
In **app.component.ts**: Navigate to component (orphan) and pass an object with a variable tableName.

> this.router.navigate( ['/orphan', {table:tableName} ] );

Step 2.
In **orphan.component.ts**, subscript to the observable to detect router changes and get the tableName from the snapshot object :

```
constructor( private route:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router) { 
      /* Listen for router events through the observable */
      router.events.subscribe( (data) => {
        // get the data from the snapshot
        this.tableName = this.route.snapshot.params.table;
      })
}
```

The component Orphan is now refreshed with the tableName value.

Comment: this seemed to work, but upon closer inspection,  is leading to all sorts of unintended consequences. the subscription is firing 'a lot', and often w null parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Huh. Maybe `student/registration`, combined with the default `pathMatch: 'prefix'` setting, makes the Angular router interpret your `navigateByUrl` as same path navigation. Just a hypothesis.

To test that, add the `pathMatch: full` to the second route:

```
{
    path: 'student/:token',
    component: GuidelinesComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
}
```

Comment: I already tried this method, but unfortunately, it didn't work. There's still the same problem.